# How I can insert array data in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to insert data by seeder:

```
public function run()
    {
        $projects = [
            [
                "name" => "project-one",
                "images" => ["image11.jpg", "image12.jpg", "image13.jpg"],
            ],
            [
                "name" => "project-two",
                "images" => ["image21.jpg", "image22.jpg", "image23.jpg"],
            ],
        ];

        Project::insert($projects);
}
```

images column is `JSON`, I get an array error on images insertion. How I can insert them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert()` method can not use any casts of the model, it will be inserted as raw. So you just need to convert the array to a json using `json_encode()` function.

```
public function run()
{
    $projects = [
        [
            "name" => "project-one",
            "images" => json_encode(["image11.jpg", "image12.jpg", "image13.jpg"]),
        ],
        [
            "name" => "project-two",
            "images" => json_encode(["image21.jpg", "image22.jpg", "image23.jpg"]),
        ],
    ];

    Project::insert($projects);
}
```